# Expo publishing just hangs

Tags: expo, expo-publish

When I `expo publish` all I ever get is:

```
› Expo SDK: 44.0.0
› Release channel: default
› Workflow: Managed

Building optimized bundles and generating sourcemaps...
Starting Metro Bundler
iOS Bundling JavaScript [====                                                            ] 6%
```

and it stays there forever. I've tried clearing all caches, deleting `.expo` and `node_modules` and still get the same result. I get the same result in CI (GitHub Actions) with a fresh container.

Does Expo publishing just occasionally go for periods when it does't work at all (because of backend issues)?

Comment: GitHub Action is still running ...

Comment: GitHub Action is still running ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW this was entirely my fault. I was generating huge bundles by importing way too much of Fontawesome.

Make sure that when you are using resources that you are careful not to add things that you don't need but that increase the bundle size.